# How to Uninstall Solana from a system?

Tags: solana-cli

I want to re-install Solana from scratch but there is no command in the solana-cli that helps to uninstall it. So what are the proper steps to completely uninstall solana from a mac system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just remove the solana installation folder. You can find it running:

```
which solana
```

the output will be something like:

```
/Users/xyz/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/solana
```

In that case you can remove the folder `/Users/xyz/.local/share/solana`

Remember to update also your environment `PATH` variable, you can check the content with:

```
 echo $PATH
```

it probably contains the solana folder you just removed.

Answer (score 1):

remove from PATH

and delete the folder of your installation - in the installation below /home/solana/**

```
downloading v1.14.6 installer
Configuration: /home/solana/.config/solana/install/config.yml
Active release directory: /home/solana/.local/share/solana/install/active_release
* Release version: v1.14.6
* Release URL: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases/download/v1.14.6/solana-release-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.bz2
Update successful
```

Comment: why have you added solana installation log

Comment: To help you give an example of where your installation might be. 

I also provided you the exact steps to remove your installation. 

Not sure why you downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an "uninstall" capability.  From config.yml in .config//install

releases_dir: /home/sol/.local/share/solana/install/releases
active_release_dir: /home/sol/.local/share/solana/install/active_release

Don't install this as root but if you do and you want to set up as a new user with existing config objects that were owned by root you will have to fix some permissions and group ownership and copy/delete some files.